# Expected value of an expected value of a joint density function

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

I had a question I was hoping for some help on:

Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be continuous random variables with joint density function:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 6(1-y_2) & \text{if $0 <= y_1 <= y_2 <= 1$ } \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

a) Find E[$Y_1|Y_2 = y_2$]

b) Use the answer you found in part a) to find E[E[$Y_1|Y_2 = y_2$]]

---

I did the work to find that a) is $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{6(1-y_2)}{6y_2 - 6y_2^2}\ dy_1 = \dfrac{1}{y_2}$$ (If you wouldn't mind checking that answer as seeing my question relies on part b), which in turn relies on a) ). However, I'm not sure at all how to approach b). Would someone assist me? Thank you so much in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I think you meant $f\left(y_1,y_2\right)$ instead of $f\left(x,y\right)$

Comment: Given $Y_2=y_2$, the joint density is a constant with respect to $y_1$, i.e. $y_1$ is conditionally uniformly distributed on $[0,y_2]$ and so has a conditional density of $\frac1{y_2}$.  But this is not the conditional expectation, which is instead $\frac{y_2}{2}$.

Comment: fonini - You are correct, I apologize for the error! Thanks for catching it!

Comment: @Henry - Did I do something wrong? Was my marginal density $6y_2 - 6y_2^2$ wrong?

Comment: $6y_2-6y_2^2$ is the marginal density for $Y_2$ on $[0,1]$, but I do not quite see why you integrate in the way you do, and instead you need to calculate (a) the conditional expectation $\displaystyle \int_{y_1=0}^{y_2} y_1\frac1{y_2}\,dy_1 = \frac{y_2}{2}$.

Comment: I thought conditional probability was found by integrating over $\dfrac{f(y_1,y_2)}{f_2(y_2)}$? It seems to me like you are integrating like standard expected value

Answer (score 0):

(a) The marginal density function for $Y_2$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{Y_2}(y_2) &=& \int_0^{y_2} 6(1-y_2)\;dy_1 \\
&=& \bigg[6(1-y_2)y_1 \bigg]_0^{y_2} \\
&=& 6y_2(1-y_2).
\end{eqnarray*}

So now,

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{Y_1|Y_2}(y_1|y_2) &=& \dfrac{f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)}{f_{Y_2}(y_2)} \\
&=& \dfrac{6(1-y_2)}{6y_2(1-y_2)} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{y_2}.
&& \\
&& \\
\therefore\quad E(Y_1\mid Y_2=y_2) &=& \int_0^{y_2} y_1\dfrac{1}{y_2}\;dy_1 \\
&=& \left[\dfrac{y_1^2}{2y_2} \right]_0^{y_2} \\
&=& \dfrac{y_2}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

(b)

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(E(Y_1\mid Y_2=y_2)) &=& \int_0^{1} E(Y_1\mid Y_2=y_2)\;f_{Y_2}(y_2)\;dy_2 \\
&=& \int_0^{1} \dfrac{y_2}{2}\;6y_2(1-y_2)\;dy_2 \\
&=& \left[y_2^3 - \frac{3}{4}y_2^4 \right]_0^1 \\
&=& 1-\dfrac{3}{4} = \dfrac{1}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}